# Crystal Reports Multiple Tables Issue

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I have a C# 2010 application that uses Crystal Reports for VS 2010. My report's purpose is to show where a person should be each day of one or more weeks. The format is this:

[image]

Please note that it is displayed in pairs, rather than a table with a general header.

It uses a DataSet that contains two DataTables, one for the header dates and one for the location.

The problem is that if I have n items in each DataTable, the report displays n^2 pairs of header / location instead of just n. The pattern is similar to a Cartesian product of the two tables.

I think it might have something to do with the linking part in the report's Database Expert but I couldn't manage to fix it. It contains no links right now.

The DataSet I use looks like this:

[image]

Comment: Post a screenshot of the relationship of the relevant tables and the query that you are using.

Comment: There is no relation between them. I think this might be the problem but I didn't manage to get it fixed... Not sure what you mean by query. I have edited the original post and added how the DataSet looks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Why do you need a table for the headers?  What are you trying to accomplish?

Why not add a date (StartOfWeek) to the WeekTable that represents the starting date of the week?  If you have that date, each column header would be a formula field that calculates the day based on the StartOfWeek field.  So much easier and it eliminates the Cartesian product that you are experiencing.

** edit **

There would be 7 header formulae (one for each day):

```
//{@Sunday}
DateAdd("d", 0, {WeekTable.StartOfWeek})

...

//{@Saturday}
DateAdd("d", 7, {WeekTable.StartOfWeek})
```

Add each field to the Page Header section and format as desired (they are Date values).

Comment: Because I need the header to be something like "Monday 21 Jun". Is there a way to make it display in this form using the way suggested by you?

Answer (score 1):

You need to link the tables to only get `n` rows.

Ideally:

- Add a unique `ID` column to the `Headers` table. Make it the one primary key, and an auto-incrementing identity.
- Add a `HeaderID` column to the `WeekTable` table, and make it a foreign key to the `Headers` table on the `ID` column.

The `Headers` table should now only include one row for each week, so if you have four employees they will all have the same `HeaderID` for a given week.

Comment: Even though it probably should have worked, it didn't. Tried as you said it, even made a number of modifications but still didn't work. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0):

You may need to explain a little further what your "header dates" are. But from what you're saying they are not linked to the main data, in which case i would probably use a subreport in the header.